# Python - function similar to VLOOKUP (Excel)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vlookup

i am trying to join two data frames but cannot get my head around the possibilities Python has to offer.

First dataframe:

```
ID MODEL   REQUESTS ORDERS
1  Golf    123      4
2  Passat  34       5
3  Model 3 500      8
4  M3      5        0
```

Second dataframe:

```
MODEL   TYPE  MAKE
Golf    Sedan Volkswagen
M3      Coupe BMW
Model 3 Sedan Tesla
```

What I want is to add another column in the first dataframe called "make" so that it looks like this:

```
ID MODEL   MAKE       REQUESTS ORDERS
1  Golf    Volkswagen 123      4
2  Passat  Volkswagen 34       5
3  Model 3 Tesla      500      8
4  M3      BMW        5        0
```

I already looked at merge, join and map but all examples just appended the required information at the end of the dataframe.

Comment: Where is Passat in the Second Dataframe?

Comment: Shouldn't merge do exactly this?

Comment: Question is about insert, so reopen

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think you can use [`insert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html) with [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by `Series` created with `df2` (if some value in column `MODEL` in `df2` is missing get `NaN`):

```
df1.insert(2, 'MAKE', df1['MODEL'].map(df2.set_index('MODEL')['MAKE']))
print (df1)
   ID    MODEL        MAKE  REQUESTS  ORDERS
0   1     Golf  Volkswagen       123       4
1   2   Passat         NaN        34       5
2   3  Model 3       Tesla       500       8
3   4       M3         BMW         5       0
```

Comment: Thank you @jezrael. Already thought about insert() and just saw your edit.

Comment: @jezrael: Thank you very much

Comment: @jezrael: A cool solution. And what should I do if I don't have unique values in df1, but they have be repeated? Because in that case I get an error: "Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects".

Comment: @TomaszPrzemski - Then counter with merge should be used, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57406428/pandas-merge-df-many-to-many-without-duplicates/57406537#57406537)

Comment: Does it matter if the 'MODEL' column name is different within the two dfs? Can I just use what it is called in df2 or do I have to rename it?

Answer (score 3):

Although not in this case, but there might be scenarios where df2 has more than two columns and you would just want to add one out of those to df1 based on a specific column as key. Here is a generic code that you may find useful.

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2[['MODEL', 'MAKE']], on = 'MODEL', how = 'left')
```

Comment: Please format code as code. stackoverflow.com/help/formatting either use `, or make indent with 4 spaces, or mark your text and press ctrl+K. Also, ideally you should explain a bit what makes your answer good/ better than the others

Answer (score 1):

The `join` method acts very similarly to a VLOOKUP. It joins a column in the first dataframe with the index of the second dataframe so you must set `MODEL` as the index in the second dataframe and only grab the `MAKE` column.

```
df.join(df1.set_index('MODEL')['MAKE'], on='MODEL')
```

Take a look at the [documentation for join](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#joining-key-columns-on-an-index) as it actually uses the word VLOOKUP.

Comment: Thank you @Ted Petrou. I saw that the documentation actually has vlookup in it. I just missed to use the ().set_index method.

Answer (score 1):

I always found merge to be an easy way to do this:

```
df1.merge(df2[['MODEL', 'MAKE']], how = 'left')
```

However, I must admit it would not be as short and nice if you wanted to call the new column something else than 'MAKE'.