# pandas merge df many to many without duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

suppose i have two df like below with the same key value on columns 'a' and 'b':

df1

```
   a  b  c
0  0  3  6
1  0  3  7
2  1  4  8
3  2  5  9
```

df2

```
   a  b   d
0  0  3  10
1  0  3  10
2  1  4  12
3  2  5  13
```

How to merge them without duplicates?

option with merging df and then delete duplicates is unsatisfactory

I try to do this by using below codes but this creates duplicate rows and significantly increases the file capacity.

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['a', 'b'], how='left', validate='many_to_many')
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['a', 'b'], how='inner')
```

Expected result:

```
   a  b  c   d
0  0  3  6  10
1  0  3  7  10
2  1  4  8  12
3  2  5  9  13
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [`.groupby().cumcount()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumcount.html) to create counter columns in both DataFrames then [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge.html):

```
df1['g'] = df1.groupby(['a', 'b']).cumcount()
df2['g'] = df2.groupby(['a', 'b']).cumcount()

df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['a', 'b', 'g'], how='inner')
print(df)
   a  b  c  g   d
0  0  3  6  0  10
1  0  3  7  1  10
2  1  4  8  0  12
3  2  5  9  0  13
```

---

The difference with the other solutions is best seen by changing the data in the second df: second `10` to `11`. My solution correctly merges the first duplicate pair `a, b` from `df1` with the first `a, b` pair from `df2`, similar for all duplicates and also for unique pairs:

```
data_dic = {
    "a": [0, 0, 1, 2],
    "b": [3, 3, 4, 5],
    "d": [10, 11, 12, 13]
}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data_dic)


df1['g'] = df1.groupby(['a', 'b']).cumcount()
df2['g'] = df2.groupby(['a', 'b']).cumcount()

df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['a', 'b', 'g'], how='inner')
print(df)

   a  b  c  g   d
0  0  3  6  0  10
1  0  3  7  1  11
2  1  4  8  0  12
3  2  5  9  0  13
```

Comment: Thank You again for nice solution. For now i don't know why but this approach creates additional 5% of data in my raw data compare to data created by removing duplicates first.

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi - I try explain difference between my solution and all another, it merge also by duplicates, first with first, second with second. Maybe the best see if test output with `df = pd.merge(
    df1.drop_duplicates(), 
    df2.drop_duplicates(), 
    on=['a', 'b'], how='inner'
)` from my changed data.

Comment: I think this feature will be useful. I'm still testing results.

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi - Maybe  I forget one very important thing - my solution merge by dupicates by `a, b` columns pairs, `kitman0804` solution remove duplicates by all columns.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the duplicated rows before merging

```
df = pd.merge(
    df1.drop_duplicates(), 
    df2.drop_duplicates(), 
    on=['a', 'b'], how='inner'
)
print(df)

#    a  b  c   d
# 0  0  3  6  10
# 1  0  3  7  10
# 2  1  4  8  12
# 3  2  5  9  13
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also drop duplicates after the merge

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='inner', on=['a', 'b']).drop_duplicates()
```

df3:

```
   a  b  c   d
0  0  3  6  10
2  0  3  7  10
4  1  4  8  12
5  2  5  9  13
```