# Left merge 2 dataframes based on 2 column, but only mismatched columns as NaN from 2nd dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, left-join

Input:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 1, 2, 2, 3], "B": [1, 2, 1, 3, 1]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"C": [1, 1, 2, 2], "D": [1, 2, 1, 4]})
```

Expected Output:

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 | 2 | Nan |
| 3 | 1 | Nan | Nan |

I tried following:

```
joined = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on=['A', 'B'], right_on=['C', 'D'], how='left')
```

Output I am getting is:

```
   A  B    C    D
0  1  1  1.0  1.0
1  1  2  1.0  2.0
2  2  1  2.0  1.0
3  2  3  NaN  NaN
4  3  1  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: Question is not clear but maybe you are just looking for only df1.join(df2)  ?

Comment: It gives me 2  3  2  4  as the 4th row, but I want 2  3  2  Nan

Comment: Why `D` isn't equal to `1` in the expected output ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the result you want by a two-stage merge, first merging column `C` of `df2` with `df1` on `A` and `C` and dropping duplicates, and then merging the result on `[C, B]` and `[C, D]`:

```py
out = (df1
    .merge(df2['C'], left_on=['A'], right_on=['C'], how='left')
    .drop_duplicates()
    .merge(df2, left_on=['C', 'B'], right_on=['C', 'D'], how='left')
)
```

Output for your sample data:

```
   A  B    C    D
0  1  1  1.0  1.0
1  1  2  1.0  2.0
2  2  1  2.0  1.0
3  2  3  2.0  NaN
4  3  1  NaN  NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't pick and choose if you're doing a merge like that. It seems like what you really want is to merge each column individually. To differentiate duplicates, you could use the index in this case, but I'm assuming that's just a fluke so I'll do [an enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57406537/4518341).

```
cols_merged = []
for col1, col2 in ('A', 'C'), ('B', 'D'):
    col_merged = pd.merge(
        df1[col1],
        df2[col2],
        left_on=[col1, df1.groupby(col1).cumcount()],
        right_on=[col2, df2.groupby(col2).cumcount()],
        how='left',
        )[col2]
    cols_merged.append(col_merged)
joined = pd.concat([df1, *cols_merged], axis=1)
joined
```

```
   A  B    C    D
0  1  1  1.0  1.0
1  1  2  1.0  2.0
2  2  1  2.0  1.0
3  2  3  2.0  NaN
4  3  1  NaN  NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you just want to compare the items in order, just `zip` and mask with [`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html):

```
tmp = pd.concat({c2: df1[c1].where(df1[c1].eq(df2[c2]))
                 for c1, c2 in zip(df1, df2)},
                axis=1)

out = df1.join(tmp)
```

Output:

```
   A  B    C    D
0  1  1  1.0  1.0
1  1  2  1.0  2.0
2  2  1  2.0  1.0
3  2  3  2.0  NaN
4  3  1  NaN  NaN
```