# Update column based on multiple columns comparison between 2 dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4], "B": [1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({"C": [1, 1, 2, 2, 3], "D": [1, 2, 1, 4, 3]})

df1['replaceFlag'] = pd.NA
```

I want to update df1.replaceFlag as 1, only if A matches with C, but B doesn't match with D.

Expected Output:

| A | B | replaceFlag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |  |
| 1 | 2 |  |
| 2 | 1 |  |
| 2 | 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 |  |

Comment: The two dataframes have different numbers of rows. How are you matching between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same code as for your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77363138/9473764), generating `replaceFlag` as

```py
(out['D'].isna()) & (~out['C'].isna())
```

which will be true when `D` doesn't match `B` and there was a match between `A` and `C`.

Full code:

```py
out = (df1
    .merge(df2['C'], left_on=['A'], right_on=['C'], how='left')
    .drop_duplicates()
    .merge(df2, left_on=['C', 'B'], right_on=['C', 'D'], how='left')
)
out['replaceFlag'] = (out['D'].isna()) & (~out['C'].isna())
```

Output for your sample data:

```
   A  B    C    D  replaceFlag
0  1  1  1.0  1.0        False
1  1  2  1.0  2.0        False
2  2  1  2.0  1.0        False
3  2  3  2.0  NaN         True
4  3  1  3.0  NaN         True
5  3  2  3.0  NaN         True
6  4  1  NaN  NaN        False
```

If you don't want columns `C` and `D` in the result, you can simply `drop` them:

```py
out.drop(columns=['C','D'], inplace=True)
```

Output:

```
   A  B  replaceFlag
0  1  1        False
1  1  2        False
2  2  1        False
3  2  3         True
4  3  1         True
5  3  2         True
6  4  1        False
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using zip:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4], "B": [1, 2, 1, 3, 1
, 2, 1]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"C": [1, 1, 2, 2, 3],       "D": [1, 2, 1, 4, 3]})


replace_Flag = []

for a,b,c,d in zip(df1.A,df1.B,df2.C,df2.D):
    if a == c and b != d:
        replace_Flag.append(1)
    else:
        replace_Flag.append(0)



# now add zeros to the end of replace_Flag
if len(replace_Flag) < len(df1.A):
    number_of_zeros_needed = len(df1.A) - len(replace_Flag)
    zeros_to_append = [0] * number_of_zeros_needed
    replace_Flag.extend(zeros_to_append)
df1["replace_Flag"] = replace_Flag

OUTPUT of df1:
   A  B  replace_Flag
0  1  1             0
1  1  2             0
2  2  1             0
3  2  3             1
4  3  1             1
5  3  2             0
6  4  1             0
```