# Python Pandas: vlookup equivalent with multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vlookup

This question is very similar to an [old one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41511730/python-function-similar-to-vlookup-excel), with an important difference: I have a key based on multiple columns. Anyway, like in the linked question, I don't want a `merge` of 2 dataframes, but an `insert` of a new column (based on a `vlookup` equivalent).
As a concrete example let's say I have a dataframe `df2.dtypes`

```
Fruit    object
Qty       int64
Year      int64
```

and another dataframe `df3.dtypes`

```
Manager    object
Fruit      object
Year        int64
```

and I assume I can build a key composed by `Fruit` and `Year` for both of them.
I've tried to do

```
df2.insert(1, 'Manager', df2.set_index(['Fruit','Year']).map(df2.set_index(['Fruit','Year'])['Manager']))
```

But I'm getting

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'map'
```

How can I rephrase it (in order to detour the issue)?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're very close to the solution, but let me first summarize what you tried to do, till the point it is correct.
So, you can indeed (as per your assumption) construct an indexed version of the dataframe `df2`:

```
df2indexed = df2.set_index(['Fruit', 'Year'])
```

and of the other dataframe `df3` as well:

```
df3indexed = df3.set_index(['Fruit', 'Year'])
```

So far so good, now the only part you were missing is that you can't apply the `map` directly to a `DataFrame`, but... you can do that to its `index`!

```
insertManager = df2indexed.index.map(df3indexed.Manager)
```

In conclusion, you will add the above said new column as you prefer:

```
df2indexed.insert(1,'Manager', insertManager)
```